# Why did drag and drop work for a lib file in VC++ but Linker->Input didn't?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is a question borne out of apocalyptic ignorance of the Visual C++ 2008 IDE.

Nevertheless, I created a project in it, and needed to include two "lib" files. I typed in the `#include "foo.h"`, copy-pasted the static libraries into the project folder, and then went to the Project Properties. Under Linker, I added the library names like you're supposed to.

However, it kept giving me the error LNK1104, saying that "fooLib.obj" cannot be opened. After about an hour of high-frequency expletive-utterances and head bashing, I resorted to dragging and dropping the .h and the lib files in the Solution Explorer as a last throw of the dice, and...MAGIC! It worked!

Can anyone please resolve the dilema of why this happened?

Comment: Next time, type "fooLib.lib" instead of "fooLib.obj".

Comment: @HansPassant:  Thanks for replying. I _did_ actually type in "fooLib.lib" in the Linker field. Also, I am not sure why the error said .obj instead of .lib, but that's what it said.

Comment: Hmya, I'll obviously go for "apocalyptic mistype" here.  There is no "Linker field", the Linker group of property pages have many settings.  Just repeat the exercise if you want to get this right for the next time.

Comment: @HansPassant I should have clarified. Apologies. I meant `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.
I added the library names, separated by white space, into the Additional Dependencies box, and the files were already copy pasted into the project folder, so I did not add the `"Additional Library Directories"`. That also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use white space to separate them, use a ; semicolon.  Fall in the pit of success by clicking the dropdown button so you can add one per line.